# haproxy Infinite page refresh loop

Tags: haproxy

On different hosts, there are two identical sites on IIS web servers, access to them is open on two ports 443 and 9000, if I turn on both hosts in haproxy, then when the site page is opened, an endless page refresh cycle occurs. It works if you disable one of the catches or specify the weight as srv1 weight 100 srv2 weight 0. How can I fix this?
My haproxy config:

```
global
    # to have these messages end up in /var/log/haproxy.log you will
    # need to:
    #
    # 1) configure syslog to accept network log events.  This is done
    #    by adding the '-r' option to the SYSLOGD_OPTIONS in
    #    /etc/sysconfig/syslog
    #
    # 2) configure local2 events to go to the /var/log/haproxy.log
    #   file. A line like the following can be added to
    #   /etc/sysconfig/syslog
    #
    #    local2.*                       /var/log/haproxy.log
    #
    log         127.0.0.1 local2
#    log /dev/log    local0
#    log /dev/log    local1 notice
    chroot      /var/lib/haproxy
    pidfile     /var/run/haproxy.pid
    maxconn     10000
    user        haproxy
    group       haproxy
    daemon

    # turn on stats unix socket
    stats socket /var/lib/haproxy/stats mode 666 level user

    ssl-default-bind-options no-sslv3
    ssl-default-bind-ciphers EECDH:+AES256:-3DES:RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:!NULL:!RC4
    # ssl-server-verify none

defaults
    mode                    http
    log                     global
    option                  httplog
    option                  dontlognull
    #option http-server-close
    #option forwardfor       except 127.0.0.0/8
    #option                  redispatch
    retries                 10
    timeout http-request    10s
    timeout queue           1m
    timeout connect         10s
    timeout client          1m
    timeout server          150s
    timeout http-keep-alive 65s
    timeout check           10s
    maxconn                 10000
    log-format "%{+Q}o\ client = %ci:%cp, server = %si:%sp path = %HU, status = %ST, %b, t_простоя = %Ti, t_отклика = %Tr, t_сеанса = %Tt, request = %r, byte = %B"

frontend stats

   bind *:8404
   http-request use-service prometheus-exporter if { path /metrics }
   no log
   stats enable
   stats uri /stats
   stats refresh 10s
   stats auth adm:123

frontend http
    bind *:80
    mode http
    redirect scheme https if !{ ssl_fc }

frontend https
    bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/tls/haproxy.pem alpn h2,http/1.1
    bind *:9000 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/tls/haproxy.pem alpn h2,http/1.1
    option              forwardfor
    option              http-keep-alive
    http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Proto https
    http-request set-header X-Client-IP %[src]

    errorloc 404 https://xxxx.com/500
    errorloc 500 https://xxxx.com/500
    errorloc 503 https://xxxx.com/500
    errorloc 504 https://xxxx.com/500

    use_backend https if { hdr(host) -i xxxx.com }
    use_backend 9000 if { hdr(host) -i xxxx.com:9000 }


backend https
    balance roundrobin
    server srv1 192.168.1.11:443 check cookie srv1 weight 80 ssl verify none
    server srv2 192.168.1.111:443 check cookie srv2 weight 20  ssl verify none

backend 9000
    balance roundrobin
    server srv1 192.168.1.11:9000 check cookie srv1 weight 80 ssl verify none
    server srv2 192.168.1.111:9000 check cookie srv2 weight 20 ssl verify none
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the "cookie" strategy for loadbalancing, but no way to set this cookie :

```
balance roundrobin
server srv1 192.168.1.11:443 check cookie srv1 weight 80 ssl verify none
server srv2 192.168.1.111:443 check cookie srv2 weight 20  ssl verify none
```

As a result, the client communicates with both server alternatively. This does not suit well with IIS (and/or underlying technos).

Simply **tell HAProxy which cookie to use/set**. For example, a cookie named `SERVERID` :

```
balance roundrobin
cookie SERVERID insert indirect nocache
server srv1 192.168.1.11:443 check cookie srv1 weight 80 ssl verify none
server srv2 192.168.1.111:443 check cookie srv2 weight 20  ssl verify none
```

- If the client already has a `SERVERID` cookie, then HAProxy sends the traffic to the corresponding server.
- If the client does not have a `SERVERID` cookie, then HAProxy chooses and instructs the client to `Set-Cookie: SERVERID=s1` for example.

Source : https://www.haproxy.com/blog/load-balancing-affinity-persistence-sticky-sessions-what-you-need-to-know/